# ToolTip as Timer

Tags: c#, wpf

My tooltip should show how long my program is running. So I try to add +1 to my tooltip, but that doesn't work.
That is my xaml code:

```
<StatusBarItem >
    <Image ToolTip="{Binding Path=ToolTipStatus}"/>
</StatusBarItem>
```

And thats my C# code:

```
private string _toolTipStatus = "0";
    private string ToolTipStatus
    {
        get { return _toolTipStatus; }
    }

private void Example()
    {            
        _toolTipStatus = _toolTipStatus + 1;          
    }
```

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? Compiler error, runtime error, what's the error message?

Comment: I've no error message. The tooltip just don't change.

Comment: There's no timer in the code you show us.

Comment: IIRC, ToolTipStatus should be public not private

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, nowhere in this code is there any reason for the UI to guess when or if your private field has changed. Second, your property is private too, so the UI can't see it either. Finally, repeatedly appending "1" to a string is going to get you a string that looks like `"11111111111111111111111111111"` after the timer fires a few times. If that's what you want, that's fine, but I think it might not be.

```
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

public class MyViewModel : ViewModelBase
{

    private int _toolTipStatus = 0;
    private int ToolTipStatus
    {
        get { return _toolTipStatus; }
        protected set {
            if (_toolTipStatus != value)
            {
                _toolTipStatus = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ToolTipStatus));
            }
        }
    }
}


private void Example()
{            
    ToolTipStatus += 1;
}
```

You won't say if you've got a viewmodel. You won't say what class your code is in or how (or if) it gets called. All your properties are private. You won't say what the XAML looks like or even if there is any. I sense a theme of obsessive secrecy here. You need to learn when to open up and share.

And you need a viewmodel, and you need it to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Answer (score 0):

You should refresh your xaml someway. The best way I think is inheriting the form from INotifyPropertyChanged.
Then declare the event and the raise method like this

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void RaisePropChanged(string name)
    {
        var eh = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (eh != null)
        {
            eh(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
```

then your property ToolTipStatus should be this:

```
private string toolTipStatus;
public string ToolTipStatus
{
    get { return toolTipStatus; }
    set
    {
        toolTipStatus = value;
        RaisePropChanged("ToolTipStatus");
    }
}
```